# Wagtail: Prefered way to disable the admin dirty forms check

Tags: javascript, django, wagtail

Ive written my own custom panels that link to adminmodels to be able to add some extended functionality to my pageobjects. But I am having trouble with the dirtycheck added by wagtails admin (onbeforeunload hook that opens an alert), that keeps on nagging the users about not leaving the page, even though I havent changed anything in the input forms.

Is there a reliable way to disable the dirtycheck for certain pagetypes?

Comment: What version of Wagtail are you running? Wagtail 2.5.2 and 2.6 (released last week) included a fix to prevent the 'dirty form' check from wrongly triggering: http://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/releases/2.5.2.html

Comment: @gasman I will try this, thanks!